# How to intialize list of objects?

Tags: c#

I got the below program from competitive programming site. They have given test case input as

```
{"array": [5, 2, [7, -1], 3, [6, [-13, 8], 4]]}
```

I want to know how to initialize the above test case sample data to a variable in C#. So that I can pass to GetProductSum method.

```
public static int GetProductSum(List<object> array)
{
    return productSumHelper(array, 1);
}

public static int productSumHelper(List<object> array, int multiplier)
{
    //some code
                //some code
    foreach (object el in array)
    {
        if (el is IList<object>)
        {
            sum += productSumHelper((List<object>)el, multiplier + 1);
        }
        else
        {
        //some code
        }
    }
    return sum * multiplier;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Is the input JSON?  Just use a JSON parser!

Answer (score 0):

I got it...

```
List<object> obj = new List<object>()
        {
            5,
            2,
            new List<object>(){ 7,-1 },
            3,
            new List<object>()
            { 
                6,
                new List<object>()
                { 
                    -13,
                    8
                },
                4
            },
        };
```

Comment: Please note that if you use the initializer syntax (like you have done here) you can also omit the round brackets.

Comment: `new List<object>() {…}` can be shortened to `new List<object> {…}`.

Comment: got it.. Thanks. :-)